# Effect of Nav-graha as per age of the person

Tags: astrology, navagraha

Does the texts dealing with Astrology mention anything about the effect of the nine planets on a person vis-a-vis their age?

For example, I have heard from several people that the Moon Planet (graha) ( सोम ग्रह)  exhibits the maximum effect on a person during his childhood, i.e., until age of 12.
Does this kind of range find mention in any authentic texts and also similarly exist for other planets too?

Comment: Vedic Astrology is a complex concept where 9 planets can impact person in several overlapping methods like Dashas(Parashari(120 years),Jaimini(70+ year),Yogini(36) etc., depending on context),Antardashas, Lagnesh etc.,I have heard that moon impacts person(in some video of KRS) by age 12 despite its dasha as Moon signifies mother and a child is raised by mother in that age gap.12-24 Mercury impacts a person and represents childhood, education and intellect.24-36 Venus impacts a person as it represents spouse & marriage and so on.Span is 12 years as its cycle of Jupiter/Guru,total 12x9=108 years

Comment: @Manu Kumar, maybe you can answer the question then?

Comment: like I mentioned, I heard it in some random video of KRS astrology(https://www.youtube.com/c/KRSchannel/videos) and found logical due to Moon-mother connection, but dont have scriptural backing for answer.